# SQL JOIN limit results to rows where specific value does not exist

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I am joining two tables using SQL. I'm joining a table which contains charter flight information and a table which contains the crew assigned. In my results, I only want to display the rows that only have a value of "Pilot" in the the crew table and not "Copilot" or both.

[image]

Comment: Please post your table structure so that i can udnerstand this more clearly.

Comment: Try @Nija's post. Can you add you tables structure..you need to inner join id's and filter it using where @Table=value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really help us out here with the schema for us to provide you with a decent query. I think the most important thing here is how do you determine who is a pilot and/or copilot and how do you relate each person to the flight.

I think something like this might help:

```
SELECT * FROM Charter C
INNER JOIN Crew ON (Charter.CHAR_TRIP = Crew.CHAR_TRIP)
WHERE Crew.Crew_Job = 'PILOT' AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Charter
                                   INNER JOIN Crew ON (Charter.CHAR_TRIP = Crew.CHAR_TRIP)
                                   WHERE Crew.Crew_Job = 'CoPilot' 
                                         AND Charter.Chart_Trip = C.ChartTrip) = 0
```

Although this might not be the cleanest solution.. it should do the work.

Comment: I added the ERD for the relevant tables. CREW_JOB would contain either "Pilot" or "Copilot". I would join them on CHAR_TRIP which would be the unique id for the trip.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT * FROM TABLE_A JOIN TABLE_B ON (TABLE_A.Value = TABLE_B.Value) WHERE TABLE_A.OtherValue = 'Pilot'`

This is off the top of my head, so some syntax may be off. The main point is the `WHERE` clause. You can specify the value that you are looking for in the column (in your case you are looking for `Pilot`).

EDIT: To prevent a value you can do something like `WHERE TABLE.VALUE != 'Copilot'`  `!=` may need to be written as `<>` depending on the what SQL it is.

EDIT2: My SQL-Server is throwing a hissy and not connecting, so this is also entirely off the top of my head and I think it's a bit of a hack-job, but I think it'll do the job. :)
 `SELECT [CHARTER].*, COUNT(*) as Tally FROM [CHARTER] JOIN [CREW] ON ([CHARTER].[CHAR_TRIP] = [CREW].[CHAR_TRIP]) WHERE [CREW].[CREW_JOB] = 'PILOT' OR [CREW].[CREW_JOB] = 'COPILOT' GROUP BY [CHARTER].* HAVING Tally = 1`
This assume that all flights have a pilot, but not all flights have a co-pilot. To get the exact display you want, you might have to use it as a sub-query (to remove the `Tally` column).

Comment: Yes, but I not only want to limit my results to rows where the value is "Pilot". For instance, if I have a Pilot and a CoPilot for a specific charter id,  I only want the rows where there is only a pilot and not a copilot or a pilot and a copilot in the crew table.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM charter ch
JOIN crew cr ON ch.char_trip = cr.char_trip
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                   FROM crew cr2
                  WHERE cr2.char_trip = ch.char_trip
                    AND cr2.crew_job != 'PILOT')
```

I think that should do the trick.  The join to the crew table in line 3 is optional, and only if you need results from that table.  The NOT EXISTS anti-join is what evaluates all crew for a given trip and checks for any that are not pilots.